# What stops a virtual machine from starting by having "too much" ram

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

In virtual box, their is a slider for how much RAM to allocate to the machine.  However, when hovering over with my cursor, it says:

> If you assign too much, the machine might not start

Since I have 40gb of RAM, what is too much, and why would alot of ram prevent it from starting?

Incase it was not apparent, I am looking for a programming related answer, not how to use the software.

Comment: Close and Downvotes, mind explaining ?

Comment: The question appears to be out of the scope of the site - you're asking a question related to virtualbox and it seems like it has nothing to do with programming at all.

Comment: @BastiM  As virtual box is open source I imagine there are programmers here who know the code.  The question can be generalized to "Why would a virtual machine software not recommend a certain amount of ram", VB is what I have so i dont know if it is true for all vm.  Does that clarify?  Im not asking how to use the software

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about VBox but, in VmWare, if you allocated too much, it wouldn't start because the memory couldn't be taken from the host OS.

The memory was allocated away from the host in one big chunk, and held for as long as the VM was running.

So it would be similar to if you tried to pre-allocate a 60G virtual disk on a drive with only 40G free. Except that would fall over at VM creation time rather than run time.

Trying to grab more memory than the host could provide is something that will cause you an issue when you *run* the VM rather than when you *create* it, because, unlike the pre-allocated disk, it's not needed until then.